# How can I execute a piece of code after doing an automatic lightweight migration?

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

I have a core data model, and I want to delete an entity in another new core data model, but when doing it (or after), I will like to execute some code (let's say, save old entities into a XML file or similar using a ObjC snippet).
I know migrating a model that only deletes an entity is easy and can be done automatically using lightweight migration, but not sure about execute some code.
Perhaps I have no choice and have to create something more complex like a mapping model, use NSRemoveEntityMappingType, subclass NSEntityMigrationPolicy and rewrite something like beginEntityMapping:manager:error: or maybe createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:entityMapping:manager:error: but not sure about this last one because there is no new entity, as what I want is removing it.

Any thoughts are welcome.
Thanks a lot for your time.
Ricardo.